# How do you add a fillet (bevel/bridge) between two complex shapes?

Tags: modeling, objects, bevel

Blender Noob here, so forgive the simple question. I've searched high and low to find out how to emulate Fusion360's "rolling ball" fillet between two objects and can't seem to find any reasonably easy way to do this. I've seen an explanation using added loops and bridging the loops, but that becomes nearly impossible with anything other than really simple shapes and really simple intersections. The basics of what I want is shown in the image below.
[image: Blender cube with angled cylinder out one corner]
[image: Fusion360 with Rolling Ball Fillet]
How do I put a fillet between an angled cylinder intersecting with 3 faces of a cube? Bevel seems like it should do it, but after 10 or more attempts with various methods, I've had no luck.  There are 3 arcs that I just want to tell Blender "bevel, 6 segments, 2mm width." But every attempt creates awful geometry. There must be a simple way. I believe I need to start by joining the two objects...or doing a Boolean Difference to create the intersection geometry. In Fusion360, this is a 2 minute task. Is there an easy way to do this in Blender?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

2 add-ons. 1) MeshMachine (Paid) or 2) Bevel after Boolean (Free). Or you will have to learn topology and choose the number of vertices and the placement of 2 meshes wisely for further topology cleanup so that it's an all (or almost) quad based geo which in turn helps in adding those fillets. OR you can add bevel in render (but very small bevels) using the bevel node.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Edit:-
[image]

Comment: I think I understand your quad geo approach and tried to emulate your steps, but am getting stuck at the actual fillet.  I created a cube, low-facet cylinder, Boolean Diff'd the cube from the cylinder to get the edges and vertices at the object intersections. Then I joined them as it appears you did. I then added edge loops slid to the vertices of the intersections and created the quad faces.  But now that I have edges defined where I want fillets, if I select those edges and apply a fillet, it's beveling the end of the cylinder and not creating a rounded fillet between the cube and cylinder.

Comment: It's an Addition Boolean not a Difference Boolean. When You Add both the structures, you are able to join the vertices of both the meshes plus there are no extra "inner" faces involved. Your geometry (i suppose) has extra face from the square.